# Ajuda em Java, expressões lógicas

Tags: java

escreva uma expressão logica para determinar se uma pessoa é um eleitor ou não. considere que são eleitores, pessoas cuja idade é maior ou igual a 16 anos

Comment: Qual erro você está tendo, onde está o código?

Answer (score 1):

Seria isto:

```
if (idade >= 16) {
  System.out.println("apto a votar");
} else {
  System.out.println("inapto a votar");
}
```